# Will NSUserDefaults remain if user quits app and are they global?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm using `NSUserDefaults` in my iOS app to record some specific info about the user's receipt state.

I'd like to confirm:

- If the user quits the app, will those defaults remain?
- Are they global, for example I'm currently using the following line to either get or set them and across different methods. I just want to be certain the data within it persists - so if I set in method1 then later method2 I use the same line to get, it will have whatever I set in method1:
  `NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

Comment: NSUserDefaults remain in the app until you clear it by code or uninstall the app

Comment: If they persist between uses of the app, they would certainly persist between method calls.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't simply try testing this before posting your question? Or why you didn't even look at documentation? The very first line says *"An interface to the user’s defaults database, where you store key-value pairs persistently across launches of your app."*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the user quits the app, will those defaults remain?

Yes, they are persistent.

> Are they global?

Global in the sense of your whole app: Yes.

Global in the sense of across apps: No. They are in the app's sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

From the NSUserDefaults documentation (see *https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults?language=objc*)

> With the exception of managed devices in educational institutions, a user’s defaults are stored locally on a single device, and persisted for backup and restore. To synchronize preferences and other data across a user’s connected devices, use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore instead.

So for your first question the answer is yes.

Accordind to your second question, doc says:

> At runtime, you use NSUserDefaults objects to read the defaults that your app uses from a user’s defaults database. NSUserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value. When you set a default value, it’s changed synchronously within your process, and asynchronously to persistent storage and other processes.

And even so, it declares that the class is thread safe, so you can be sure about persistent results (for your second answer).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally with @Nikolai Ruhe answer.

> if I set in method1 then later method2 I use the same line to get, it will have whatever I set in method1: NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

**The UserDefaults class is thread-safe.**

Answer (score 0):

Two further points.

The uselessness of `synchronize` has grown up gradually through versions of iOS. It used to be essential; then advisable; then unnecessary. I can’t give you an exact timeline but a lot of it depends on how far back in iOS you want your app to work.

If you try to test some of these things in Xcode, beware. Up to and including iOS 11, `synchronize` does not write all the way to disk, but only puts data in a “lazy write” queue. Pressing the Stop button in Xcode (or pressing Run and allowing Xcode to stop the previous running app automatically) shuts everything down abruptly, more abruptly than anything a user can do, and the lazy writes are not written out, but lost. This is confusing while you are resting!! I filed a report on it and was told by Apple that (as Microfot would put it) “This behaviour is by design”.

But just to be clear: that second point does not present a problem for real apps in a real environment, only when you are trying to test “save and restart” scenarios. Waiting 5-10 seconds seems to be long enough for the flushed data to make it all the way to disk.